# Strange profiling results regarding heap size and surviving generations

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, profiling, heap-size

I am writing a simple program for simulating Texas hold 'em. I wanted to test running it in a loop for a long time to test any performance or other issues. I ran the program for four hours and what it did during the time:

1. Shuffles the card deck.
2. Deals five cards for the dealer and two cards for each of the ten players.
3. Evaluates each player's hand.
4. Removes the dealer's and players' cards.
5. Resets each player's hand.
6. Repeat from step 1.

The program ran just fine in the beginning. According to the NetBeans profiler, CPU and GC times stayed stable and the heap sizes, both max and used, looked exactly as they should during the whole runtime (at least I think they're supposed to look like that). However, the surviving generations metric started to rise linearly at around three hours in. During most of the program runtime, the surviving generations value was ranging from two to six. In the end, it peaked at a max of 200+ something, I think it was 218.

Now I'm wondering why this is happening, since all the program does is repeat a couple of actions, which takes a millisecond at most, for about one billion times. Why does this behaviour start so abruptly and only after three hours of runtime? Is some variable somehow getting "stuck", making garbage collection not able to clean it? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is an image showing the profiling graphs:
[image: Here is an image showing the profiling graphs.]

Comment: You've posted the algorithm you're using but to make a proper analysis it would be helpful if you could post the code (assuming it's not too big).

Comment: Mind that when you connect a monitoring tool that uses JMX, handling the connection causes CPU load and garbage creation on its own. With a program as simple as you described, this monitoring overhead may outweigh the actual program’s resource consumption. But it also shouldn’t exhibit such a behavior. Considering that the overall memory consumption didn’t change, apparently, this might be some noise, exaggerated like looking through a strong lens. It would be interesting what happens when you let this run for some more hours…